# How judicious should I be with up and down votes?

Tags: discussion, voting, new-users

Understanding that voting is done at the initiative of each user individually, is there a rough basis for how often one should up or downvote, in terms of minimum acceptability? The conditions for *why* are clear enough for me; upvote purposeful, supported questions and relevant, complete answers which deliver content clearly and completely. But is it proper to upvote each answer that satisfies those conditions, or just the best one? Should I upvote a question only if it satisfies a certain degree of merit, or whenever it seems useful and unique? Is it appropriate to downvote a poorly-written question, even if the basic point has merit (and just needs a competent rewrite)? Conversely, should mundane but acceptably-written posts be penalized? (In all cases, observing the basic parameters for an up or down vote.)

Naturally, when and how a user votes is entirely discretionary (at least for as long as they retain that privilege), and every user will behave slightly differently. When and which way a vote is cast should always be dependent on the merit and quality of the post it's assigned to. But is it frowned upon to vote on every good question and answer you turn eyes upon? Or is it better to issue votes sparingly and only when something stands out as being exceptional (in one way or the other)?

Ordinarily, I wouldn't bother asking, but since there are guidelines and rules about other voting phenomena (serial voting, for one), I thought it might be important. Is there an established resource for this? I'm looking for guidelines or common practice, *per se*, rather than rules.

Comment: You are not obliged to review every answer, just those you happened to read and have found to be useful.

Comment: Oh, I know. But if I ask or view a question, and I find that it has several useful answers, is it reasonable (or at least _permissible_) to upvote every one that I consider helpful, if I want to?

Comment: of course, why not?

Comment: It's easy to imagine there being well-established users with a lot of rep who would say something like, "If you upvote every answer, then you haven't upvoted _any_ of them," by way of the argument, "You haven't said any one is better than any other."
Now, I don't agree with that argument, because I don't think that's the purpose of up or down votes, but I'm also a new user, and new users are timid little creatures that doubt practically every keystroke they commit.

Or that recklessly bang off whatever thing flies into their head.
You know. One or the other.

(In short, "paranoia.")

Comment: Ah, but the way reputation works here is not a zero-sum game. Voting is an exercise..you might be doing it better over time, but don't worry about not doing it "perfectly".

Comment: I'd figured that it was more of a mechanism for rewarding any who contribute, rather than singling out "the best posts," but I'd rather ask and be safe than do something clumsy and make waves. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a couple possible ways to interpret the guidelines, given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up:

> Voting up is how the community indicates which questions and answers are most useful and appropriate... Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up! You have a limited number of votes per day, so use them wisely.

I could interpret "*especially* useful" simply as one of the N best posts I expect to see today, where N is the number of upvotes I get per day.

Alternatively, and I think most appropriately, it could be something that I think others are likely to find, (because, for instance, the question is worded clearly enough) and that they will think is useful to answer their similar question. This is still fairly rare, but includes questions too basic for me, or those that I answer. I could imagine upvoting maybe as many as a dozen questions a day, if I looked at everything coming in. This seems to preclude almost ever earning to badge for using up your votes, even on a day that I spend all of on SO.

Lastly, it could be something I personally find useful (relatively rare, and almost never including a question that I post a reply to.) This would lead to me using about 1 upvote a month, which seems unreasonable since you are given more than 1 per day.

So, I'm left with something between the first and second answer as my personal guidelines.