# The Triage review queue gives contradictory voting directions

Tags: discussion, upvotes

Should we as users expect a minimum level of quality before a question "deserves" an upvote, or is a question that conforms to the site rules, and asks a clear and meaningful question, "by default" get an upvote? I would expect the site directions to provide a clear answer, but I am confused by the directions on the site.

According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up:

> Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up! You have a limited number of votes per day, so use them wisely.

But the advice given in the "Review | Triage" queue, where if a post "Looks OK," you are prompted to upvote it; this seems like a clear contrast to "Especially Useful".

I would assume one of the two should have a different message, but perhaps I'm over-thinking things.

Comment: You're not alone with this, many people are under the impression that the Triage upvote button should not be there. Please make sure to _not_ upvote things that are just above being closeable; as the privilege guidance says upvotes should be used for content that you genuinely feel is useful.

Comment: I agree; there is still a significant gap between "Especially useful" and "Just above Closeable" (Which should be "needs improvement" in the queue, not "Looks OK"). I could interpret "Especially" simply as one of the twenty best posts I expect to see today. Alternatively, it could be something I personally find useful (relatively rare), or as something that I think others are likely to find, and will think is useful (still fairly rare).

Comment: To upvote, I take a look at a question which may interest me. If it is clear and fairly well written, and I don't know the answer, I try to google it. I try 2 or 3 different search queries, and if I can't find the answer in the first 10 results of either of them, I upvote it. This is about 0.1% of the questions I vote on (rough estimate).

Comment: The tooltip of the upvote button says: "This question shows research effort; **it is useful** and clear". Questions can satisfy all the guidelines of the site and not be useful *for you*, and as such you shouldn't upvote them (which doesn't imply that you should downvote them!). I don't think that you should be totally impartial and start thinking if there exist one circumstance where someone could find it useful and hence upvote it. You should decide if it is useful *for yourself*. If everybody does this the number of votes will reflect how many people a question/answer can help.

Comment: This isn't the same question as yours exactly, but it might be on the same sort of wavelength. Could offer some insight, perhaps. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280074/how-judicious-should-i-be-with-up-and-down-votes

Comment: There's still a gap, IMO, between "Looks OK" at the low end and "deserves upvote". There are a fair number of questions that are OK, but not amazing: they can't meaningfully be improved (without enormous effort and reimagining the question), but are merely acceptable, not anything like the higher-quality questions upvotes are for.

Comment: @Augusta - it's on the same wavelength, but disappointingly, there seems to be little in the way of answers there either.

Comment: @Bakuriu, I think most people who've been around a bit get a sense of what sorts of questions are "useful", whether or not they personally will have use for an answer.

Comment: I find this question to be especially useful.

Comment: @DavidManheim "*Which should be 'needs improvement' in the queue, not 'Looks OK')*" You want to replace "Looks Ok" with "Needs Improvement"? The three options are a logical and natural range of choices - "Is ok", "Needs attention", and "Can't be fixed".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's some controversy over that upvote prompt in the Triage queue, and a lot of people feel that it is out of place. That queue, by the way, is still in its trial period, so things can certainly change before it's a complete review queue.

In general, voting is the most subjective thing we do here, and no one can really tell *you* how to use your own votes; use them however you'd like. (And now I'm going to tell you how you should use them even though I said that no one can really tell you how to use your own votes.)

You should vote up questions that are helpful to you in some way or those which you deem worthy of any kind of praise. You should vote down questions that lack research, are not helpful (not just to you, but to anyone), and those which are devoid of any effort whatsoever.

There is a rift between "Looks OK" and upvote-worthy, in my opinion (which of course is my own because I choose how to use my own votes). In fact, in other queues, "Looks OK" used to be "Looks Good" and was changed to the former for the very same reason, so I presume that this measure in the Triage queue is an experiment to try to get people to vote more.

Comment: I'll just note that somewhere in the calculus of deciding what to upvote is that there are things worth upvoting because they will be useful to others,  not just those that happen to help you. This means that findable, clear questions that have basic answers, or useful tips on what to do to diagnose an error you are not having might be worth an upvote - even if you find them useless.

Comment: @DavidManheim Agreed (I tried to imply that in the downvote section, but I was a bit vague).

Answer (score -1):

### We don't vote enough

Too many users are keen to *downvote* "*poor*" questions, but don't have the same "passion" to *upvote* their opposites - "*not-poor*" questions.

I think the problem is we (community) only upvote *good* ones. We're not correctly defining all the ones in the middle with even a couple of votes, to more consistently signify either:
*"meh, not really ok"* -1
or
*"meh, is ok".* +1

So those "meh" questions are *all* sat at 0 votes and so voting is defining them as equal, when they are really not.

Look at the listing page, so many are sat at *0 votes*!

Most of us don't upvote based on the question quality being "*not poor*", but we should do really, even if just to net 2 votes.
Which leads me to...

### "Just above closable"

l4mpi stated:

> Please make sure to *not* upvote things that are just above being closeable;

41 of you voted to agree, however, "just above being closable" is still an "acceptable" question, otherwise we'd downvote and/or close it.

Let me quote the reverse of that, and see what you think:

> Please make sure to *not downvote* things that are *only just* "closable";

Do you agree with that?
Or do you want to downvote that question because it was "closable" - no matter how closable it was, regardless of if it was "only just" closable, you want to downvote it?

A question is either closable or it is not, and no matter how far into that margin it is, it is still in that defined margin.
Which means if closable, we can downvote, if not closable, we can upvote.

### So, back on topic

AstroCB hit the nail on the head with:

> That queue, by the way, is still in its trial period, so things can certainly change before it's a complete review queue.

So I agree with Stack trying to remind or promote upvoting on new user questions, whever they can, as if they're worthy of an upvote we should be upvoting.

I think it's the wording which is what has us a little *excited*:

"*Remember to upvote*" is a bit too close to sounding like upvoting is some obligation, or duty of some kind. Rather than entirely up to us whether we even upvote at all, let alone based on some criteria.

There is no criteria to define when to vote, guidelines yes.

The sentence should be changed to only sound like a *reminder* that voting is good for the site.

> Please remember that upvoting clear, useful, well-researched questions encourages the author and others to ask good questions

### "Looks ok"

You might think the question is amazing, perfect in every way, you'd upvote 20 times if you could, however you will still be stating "Looks ok".

"Looks ok" is not your actual opinion on the question, it's just a system title to map a certain outcome of the review.

Comment: Disagree with your premise. There is so much crap being upvoted, there are counter-upvotes to percieved "unjust" downvotes, upvotes because "OP is new", etc, etc. See also the recent question quality discussions. I'd rather say we don't _downvote_ enough. And no, reversing my comment is a fallacy - with a few exceptions (e.g. a good question, but posted in the wrong community) it's a quality scale; questions that are closeable due to being unclear/too broad definitely fall into the "not useful" category, and the "unclear" even has an overlap with the DV reason.

Comment: "So much crap being upvoted" .. is nothing to do with my answer. The same is true that too many "ok" questions are being downvoted, and often to a mad degree (like -6). There are all sorts of happenings and parameters, but their existence doesn't change my argument above.

Comment: "*questions that are closeable due to being unclear/too broad definitely fall into the "not useful" category*" - Not always, that's why we have the "locked" questions. They are closable based on site requirements/criteria, and often questions which bring great information or useful answers are closed, and sometimes deleted, due to daft close reasons. Also, questions "just above closable" can be very useful. Again, the site has generic rules which don't always work in the favour of providing information which would be useful to "someone" or a number of people.

Comment: Your answer starts with "We don't upvote enough", which is what I address with my comment. I'd say people upvote more than enough crap already. You might be correct that they don't upvote enough things that actually deserve it, but in general I disagree with that statement. And while I do like your version of the "voting reminder" way better than what is currently in place, I don't yet agree that it should be there at all.

Comment: And yes, there are always exceptions to the rules and the closing guidances; but my point is that most questions that are _just above being closeable_ are still pretty bad; e.g. show no research, answerable but not especially clear, provides code to reproduce the error but it's a huge code dump and there's no attempt at reducing it to a minimal example, etc. Those should definitely be downvoted.

Comment: So people upvote "too much" because they upvote incorrectly? That's not right, accurately they "upvote incorrectly". And that does not stop my argument being correct that people do not upvote "ok" questions as much as they downvote "only just not ok" ones.

Comment: You say _people do not upvote "ok" questions as much as they downvote "only just not ok" ones_ - well, why should they? Things should be upvoted if they are _useful_, and downvoted if they are not. "just not ok" equals "barely downvoteable", but "ok" does not equal "useful". There is a middle ground where a question can just exist without being voted upon, and I see nothing wrong with that. I'd argue "barely useful" questions are upvoted all the time.

Comment: Yes some questions don't necessarily require any vote at all, but as I said in my answer, go see the question listing. "Most" questions are 0 votes (net, of course). That cannot be right, especially as you are arguing that "most questions just above being closed should be downvoted." - so, as I said in my answer, we are not voting enough...(I'll change the heading from not upvoting enough, as my answer is not actually only about lack of upvote)

Comment: My feeling is that 0 votes is a bit like a "C" on a letter grading scale of A, B, C, D, F. It is adequate and meets the minimum requirements. If you want a B (a small number of UV), you'll need to work for it. The question should be clear and useful to a number of people in the tags specified. If you want an A (100+ UV), it should be an exceptional question. If you don't put effort into the question, it's unclear or missing stuff, you might pass with a D (small number of DV), but it's not so good. Likewise, an F (more than 10 DV?) you're likely to get booted from the class :).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I see the similarity you mention, they are two different things entirely, and in some ways the two don't marry up. Some of the questions are probs correct to have 0 votes, but given the total number of question on any list page at 0 votes, there are *many* which should not be 0. If this is not because "we're not voting enough" then what is it?

Comment: Seems to be a following of users agreeing with I4mpi, however I don't understand how there is an argument stating "many just above closable should be downvoted" yet at the same time many are at 0 votes, but people don't agree "we don't vote enough". If more should have been downvoted, then why haven't they? And it *is not* just too many not being downvoted enough. I think most people's standards for an "upvote" is **Way** too high!

Comment: @l4mpi - Do you think this should be upvoted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050624/more-than-one-htmlspecialchars-string-in-php-mysql ? This is the sort of question I meant when I said we don't upvote enough "not-poor" questions. Even though it likely offers no use to anyone other than the OP's localised issue, it's easy to read, well laid out, "intro" "code" "problem" "what want to happen". I'm not debating btw, just wondering what you think.

Comment: That's exactly the type of question that is IMO upvoted too often (although it's not total crap, unlike many other questions that make me want to ban the upvoters). OP forgot or didn't know to add `{}` to the `while`. That is a beginner mistake which is simply _not useful_ to duplicate a thousand times on SO, and I'd bet multiple variants of it are asked daily across PHP, Java, C etc. +3 is already more than enough IMO, I could understand DVs as research didn't happen or failed miserably - reading any decent tutorial, looking at example code, or experimenting would all have solved the issue.

Comment: I agree, it's not useful to anyone else, but while Stack is supposed to be a resource for everyone, it also a "ask a question get some help" site too. And I agree it is a beginner / noob question, but they do not annoy me so much when they have at least spent *their* time making the question easy to answer. And is why I say give an upvote, because they asked a well written, concise question on a "*Q&A*" site.. It is pointless, and they could have probs found their answer by reading more, but how do you define what level of knowledge or understanding is acceptable to be able to ask a question?

Comment: Which leads me to, if it's acceptable, and albeit noob it is "noob-but-well-asked", so why not an upvote or two to separate it from the "noob-but-poorly-asked-lazy" ones? Otherwise we have no separation, and end up, as we do have right now, a load of questions at 0 votes. I still stand by the fact the we don't vote enough - up or down, but mostly up. And the lack of up votes is because people think as you do (nothing wrong with that, we're both entitled to our views). I think "good" questions worthy of an upvote or 2 is not *only* defined by "useful to others" and "higher level of PHP". (imo)

Comment: _it is also a "ask a question get some help" site too_ not really IMO, but still, OP did get help, isn't that enough? Why should he also gain rep? And yes, I appreciate that he's able to ask a decently formulated question, which is why I didn't DV; but the same question with worse formatting or a bigger code dump instead of a concise example would get a DV and possibly CV from me. As to what level of knowlede is acceptable, I'd at least except basic language-agnostic programming knowledge (loops, vars, basic scoping and OO etc) and everything that's covered in an entry level language tutorial.

Comment: As to why I'd not upvote, I agree we should separate those questions from the "noob and poorly asked" ones, but that should work by _downvoting and closevoting the bad questions_. As far as I see it, DVs should mean "that's a bad question, don't do that again", UVs should mean "that's a good/useful question, please have some rep and ask more of those", and there is a middle ground where a question is neither good enough for an UV nor bad enough for a DV. The question you linked IMO falls into this middle ground and definitely leans more towards the DV side.

Comment: You know, I truly don't disagree with what you say. I don't fault your logic of DV poor ones, upvote good ones, leave "meh" ones at 0 and answer if Q is ok. Our difference is simply I will upvote some of the "meh" ones. To separate them from the crap ones, and give the new users motivation to continue to spend time writing well presented questions. And also as bringing them a little rep means they can soon upvote answers they get, and eventually help out on the site in other ways. Otherwise they'll be forever stuck asking "meh" questions and we might never get anything more from them.

Comment: We've bashed this enough, and know where each other stands. At least we both have *logic* in our ways if nothing else. Just boils down to a personal choice really. :)